# JavaFX UI Frozen when performing Task in new Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have a problem getting the JavaFX UI to keep active while performing a background Task.
I have set up this very simple code -

```java
@FXML
ProgressBar prgbProgress;

@FXML
private void onClick(ActionEvent event) {
      Task <Void> t = new Task <Void> () {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            updateProgress(i, 9);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
          }
          return null;
        }
      };
      prgbProgress.progressProperty().bind(t.progressProperty());
      new Thread(t).run();
}
```

What I expect to happen is to have the progress bar update every ~1 second until the task is complete. Instead, the UI completely freezes for 10 seconds, after which the progress bar appears completed.
Just to make it clear - the problem isn't only that all of the updates appear at once in the end, but also that the UI is completely unresponsive until then.

I have read just about any other question about this topic, but can't find an answer. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `run()` -> `start()`. You just ran the `Thread` instance as a `Runnable` in the current thread.

Comment: Yes, as @MarkoTopolnik wrote, you're not executing `Task` in a new `Thread`. Try `new Thread(t).start();`

Comment: Thanks! Now I feel really stupid. The difference between `run` and `start` could be made more clear, though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *start()* instead of *run()*

```
@FXML
ProgressBar prgbProgress;

@FXML
private void onClick(ActionEvent event) {
      Task <Void> t = new Task <Void> () {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            updateProgress(i, 9);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
          }
          return null;
        }
      };
      prgbProgress.progressProperty().bind(t.progressProperty());
      //new Thread(t).run(); // wrong
      new Thread(t).start(); // right
}
```

Comment: what's the difference ?