# JavaFX refresh view before long task

Tags: javafx

I have to perform a long running task wihin the gui.
I thought to block the user input and gray the window while doing it.
For this, I added a full-scene pane to the form:

```
<Pane
    visible="false"
    opacity="0.50"
    style="-fx-background-color: gray;"
    fx:id="paneBlocker" />
```

The code I meant to use:

```
private void doLongTask() {
    showBlocker(true); // Shows the blocker pane and blocks the input

    Platform.runLater( () -> {
        longTask();
        otherTaskModifyingGui();
        showBlocker(false); // Hide blocker
    });
}
```

I thought it would be asynchronous so the changes done in `showBlocker` will take affect, but it doesn't.

Also I tried to move the long task to another thread:

```
private void doLongTask() {
    showBlocker(true);

    new Thread(() -> {
        longTask();

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
        otherTaskModifyingGui();
        showBlocker(false);
        });
    }).run();
}
```

It doesn't work either. :-(

How can I force the GUI to show the blocker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590651/javafx-ui-frozen-when-performing-task-in-new-thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590651/javafx-ui-frozen-when-performing-task-in-new-thread)

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaFX Task API: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

The Task offers various hooks for its life-cycle, like

- [setOnScheduled()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnScheduled-javafx.event.EventHandler-)
- [setOnSucceeded()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnSucceeded-javafx.event.EventHandler-)

without the need to do `Platform.runLater()` calls.